# Queryable decoration with HttpResponseException issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

When I keep in the Queryable, it will give the following error, how would I handle throwing errors if I am using the decorator [Queryable]:

*Queries can not be applied to a response content of type 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'. The response content must be an ObjectContent.*

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Queryable]
    [ActionName("ById")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Example))]
    public IQueryable<Example> Get(ODataQueryOptions opts, Guid actionuniqueid)
    {
        if (actionuniqueid.ToString() == "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
        {
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
            {
                Content =
                    new StringContent(
                    string.Format(
                        "No Example for ID: {0}", actionuniqueid)),
                ReasonPhrase = "Missing parameter"
            };
            throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
    {
        Content =
           new ObjectContent(typeof(string),
                string.Format("No Example for ID: {0}", actionuniqueid)),
                new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()),
        ReasonPhrase = "Missing parameter"
    };
```